# Matlab equivalent of Python Panda's dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, matlab, matlab-table

If I have a `pandas.DataFrame` in python I can inspect the data types for the DataFrame with the `dtypes` [attribute](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html). How can I do the same with a Matlab table? I poked around the `Properties` mechanism but didn't find anything type oriented there.

Comment: Isn't there a Property called `VariableTypes`? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html

Comment: If I try a `.` tab completion after Properties I get presented with `Description`, `DimensionNames`, `RowNames`, `UserData`, `VariableContinuity`, `VariableDescriptions`, `VariableNames`, and `VariableUnits`. I'm in Matlab 2018a. Upon reading the doc it seems VariableTypes is an input string to coerce a data type.

Comment: Looks like there's also a [vartype](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vartype.html) function which grabs variables from a `table` of a certain type. But that's a different operation too. I'm trying to do something more introspective than something selective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you can call the following:

```
varfun(@class,t,'OutputFormat',table)


class_var1   class_var2    class_var3    class_var4 
__________   __________    __________    __________

double       double        double        double
```

where `t` is your table. I am referencing the answer [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304728-getting-data-types-of-table).

Further documentation on `varfun` is available [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varfun.html) as well.

Comment: Nice find, its choking on my particular table, but I think because it has some nested matrix type or something. When I inspect it in the DataInspector there are some "merged" columns for some of the variables, eg variable 2 spans 4 columns: `class(t) ; ans = 'table'; varfun(@class,t,'OutputFormat',cell) ; Error using cell Not enough input arguments.`

Comment: @jxramos: If you want to find the class for an individual column, you can also simply say `class(t.var1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one way to get this information (while unfortunately getting a bunch of other things) is with a simple call to [summary](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/summary.html).

Here's some sample output

```
K>> summary(t)

Variables:

    var1: 2966185×1 double

        Units:  sec
        Values:

            Min       56.207
            Median    7466.7
            Max        14878

    var2: 2966185×4 double

        Values:
                        var2_1        var2_2      var2_3      var2_4
                      ________    __________    ________    ________

            Min       -0.99966      -0.99901    -0.99887    -0.99998
            Median     0.01644    -0.0044018     0.12838      0.1564
            Max        0.98176       0.96433     0.99998           1

    var3: 2966185×3 double

        Units:  g
        Values:
                         var3_1        var3_2        var3_3
                      __________    _________    __________

            Min           -2.779      -3.1366       -3.6089
            Median    -0.0002124    -0.002221    -0.0020435
            Max           3.7874       5.9634        2.8443


    var4: 2966185×1 double

        Values:

            Min          0
            Median       5
            Max          5
```

Comment: Is this telling the data type though?

Comment: @rahlf23, sure, eg `var1: 2966185×1 double`, it's a double column vector, and var 2 and 3 are matrices of double. That appears to be what broke the `varfun` solution which probably handles single dimension variables.